# I can't get RPI.GPIO working

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, rpi.gpio

I have just gotten a raspberry pi 3 model b for x-mas. In a short time I have come a long way. In a python script that I am making, I need to control two buttons (sense what one is pressed) so button.wait_for_press wont work. From my understanding, you can only wait for one gpio input at a time with this. In my research, I have found GPIO.event_detected(2) or whatever input you need. The problem is, I have to use: import 'RPI.GPIO as GPIO' at the start. However, my python cant find the module. I get this error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/python project/Simon.py", line 4, in 
    import RPI.GPIO as GPIO
ImportError: No module named RPI.GPIO

I have done some research and found that rpi.gpio is not installed properly. I looked up many tutorials and I have done what they said. I have done console commands and manually downloading it but python gives the same error. The weird thing is, it is supposed to come installed on raspbian and that is what I am running. My script is almost working and pretty much done. I will be so happy and so proud of myself when i finally get it working because it is amazing for my level of skill. Please help.

The first thing that I need help with is installing RPI.GPIO properly and in the right file. I have tried many things so if it doesn't work, I would appreciate knowing this fact: If I re install Raspbian, would I loose my current files and scripts. I would like to know that because it might come down to re installing Raspbian if nothing works. For if nothing works, I would like to know if you have any ideas to replace what I have below. It is not my script but it uses the same function.

```
    from time import sleep
    import RPI.GPIO as GPIO

    while True:
        if GPIO.event_detected(2):
            print "You Pressed Button 1"
            sleep(1)
        if GPIO.event_detected(4):
            print "You Pressed Button 2"
            sleep(1)
```

I have an idea, would this work?:

```
    from time import sleep
    from gpiozero import button

    while True:
        button = Button(2)
        button.when_pressed = print "you pressed button 1"
        sleep(1)
        button = Button(4)
        button.when_pressed = print "you pressed button 1"
```

Thank you so much for your help and info ahead of time!
-Rymazon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct the RPi GPIO module does come preinstalled on recent versions of Raspbian, and is almost certainly already installed. The problem is that the name of the Library is wrong.

Change this line:

`import RPI.GPIO as GPIO`

to this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
```

**Note** the lowercase **i**. Python is case sensitive; Pi and PI do not refer to the same thing.

Yes reinstalling will erase any work or settings you have modified. Reflashing (reinstalling Raspbian) the SD card is like reformatting your hard drive.

Comment: Thank you so much. I never would of noticed that lowercase 'I'. And thanks for being so fast! I really appreciate it.